# How to move everything apart from a specific element (LUA game development)

Tags: lua

I've just begun working on some LUA and I'm interested in using it in game dev, having been using Javascript before.  The main query that I have is that I would like my "user" - a class with a draw function that draws a circle, to remain in the middle of the screen and move everything around it (including other possible entities such as characters).  How would I go about doing this, and is there a better logic than the following I have formulated?

I have considered separating the user from the rest of the objects that would appear on screen and thus moving this "background" instead of moving the use (like I currently have), but I am not sure whether this is the "best" way in order to achieve this effect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you define "best" here? If you don't define which requirements the solution should meet you can't ask for the best solution as there is no measurement for its quality.
Simply asking for something best is considered off-topic on SO as answers will be purely opinion based.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback, in general I guess I mean "how" (thus have changed the title accordingly) to do what I have stated above, hopefully this fulfills the requirements of posts a bit better.

Comment: Lua is a proper name, not an ACRONYM.